# Nutch 1.19 / Solr 9.4.0 How to point Nutch to the Solr instance?

Tags: solr, nutch

I've been trying to get Solr and Nutch setup, following the tutorial [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NUTCH/NutchTutorial).

However, I'm stuck at the end of the tutorial where it says:
After that you need to point Nutch to the Solr instance:

(Nutch 1.15 and later) edit the file conf/index-writers.xml, see [IndexWriters](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NUTCH/IndexWriters)

How exactly should I edit the file to point Nutch to the Solr instance?

I looked at the linked IndexWriters page but couldn't find any answers.

I used the default core name "nutch".

I was able to get Nutch to crawl but the data is not seen in the Solr core.

Answer (score 0):

according to mentioned doc it could end up in a simple file as:

```
<writers xmlns="http://lucene.apache.org/nutch"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://lucene.apache.org/nutch index-writers.xsd"><writer id="indexer_solr_1" class="org.apache.nutch.indexwriter.solr.SolrIndexWriter">
<parameters>
  <param name="url" value="YOUR_SOLR_URL_HERE_INCL_SLASH_SOLR"/>
</parameters>
<mapping>
  <copy/>
  <rename/>
  <remove/>
</mapping></writer></writers>
```